# Find length of streak in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where a column depicts an integer time index, and I want to add a column that stores whether a row is part of a streak and how long the streak is. For example, given the `time` column, I would like to compute a `streak` column, like so

```
time    streak
0       3
1       3
2       3
4       2
5       2
5       2
9       1
11      1
11      1
```

The first three lines are part of a streak of three since indices 0,1,2 are contiguous. The following three lines have a streak of 2 since indices 4,5 are also contiguous; index 5 is repeated, but this shouldn't count when determining the length of a streak. Finally, the last three lines are not contiguous to anything else, so they have a streak of 1. Notice that sometimes more than one row can have the same `time`. I need to count the length of the streak in time units, so that multiple entries don't affect the length of the streak, and lines with the same time index have the same streak length. Bear in mind that other columns (not shown) are stored in the dataframe.

How do I get the value? I tried playing around with `groupby`, `shift` and similar functions, but didn't quite get very far.

EDIT: sorry, I forgot to specify that sometimes the `time` index can be repeated. I expanded on the question to keep this into account.

Comment: I could swear I saw the same question a week or two ago.

Comment: Wasn't me! I did find a similar question, but I couldn't find how to apply it to my problem. Also it used an outdated system with `cumsum`, which supposedly is superseded by the new sort = False option in groupby.

Comment: Not sure in what sense `cumsum` is "outdated"? It's not deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Using `diff` find the whether it continue or not (equal to 1 ), then `cumsum` with the condition match , then we using `groupby` + `transform` `szie`

```
s=df.time.diff().fillna(1).ne(1).cumsum()
s.groupby(s).transform('size')
Out[396]: 
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
5    1
6    1
Name: time, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Great! Thanks - however I forgot to mention that multiple rows with the same time might be present, and they should all have the same streak length, as discussed in the edit of the question. Could you please fix it so that it works in that case too?

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to Wen's answer, just using `value_counts` which I feel is a tiny bit more pandorable.

```
time = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 11])

# Give each row a streak id by incrementing whenever the difference isn't 1
streak = (time.diff() != 1).cumsum()

# Maps each id to the number of times the id occurs
result = streak.map(streak.value_counts())

print(result)
Out:
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
5    1
6    1
```

Edit: here's a solution to cater for the new case added to the question where there may be duplicate times. Note we are using `diff > 1` to find new streaks; this is using the assumption that the times are (not necessarily strictly now) increasing integers. The possible duplication just means we have to `drop_duplicates` before working out the streak id count for the mapping.

```
time = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 9, 11, 11])

result = (time.diff() > 1).cumsum().map(
    (time.drop_duplicates().diff() > 1).cumsum().value_counts()
)

print(result)
Out:
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    1
7    1
8    1
```

Comment: Great! Thanks - however I forgot to mention that multiple rows with the same time might be present, and they should all have the same streak length, as discussed in the edit of the question. Could you please fix it so that it works in that case too?

Comment: If you take the time to understand the solutions provided I feel that this shouldn't be too hard for you -- it's not a complicated fix. I've edited my answer to take care of the new information.